# Smarty Template: printing 2 columns in every iteration

Tags: php, smarty

i have a php script that populates and assing my smarty array. i want to print two columns in one row then start another row.

```
  {section name=customer loop=$custid}

   <tr>

    // would love to start another loop here which will loop two times 
    <td>$custid<td>

    // and end loop here

    </tr>

   {/section}
```

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.for.tpl

Comment: Chris i have seen that .. but its not really what i am looking for

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you are looking for? You said you wanted a loop that runs twice. That is exactly what `for` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mod operator with the current loop index, something like this (not tested) would probably work:

```
{section name=customer loop=$custid}
    {assign var="column" value=$smarty.section.customer.index%2}

    {if $column==0}<tr>{/if}
    <td>$custid<td>
    {if $column==1 || $smarty.section.customer.last}</tr>{/if}
{/section}
```